# Allowing transition to a state in UI Router from only specific states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI Router and trying to figure out how to allow a user to access a state from only two other states. Otherwise, the user should be redirected to the home state.

In this instance, I only want the user to be able to access the payment.details state from the payment.confirmation state and from the selection state.

I'm not sure how to combine the two rules below:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        if (fromState.name !== 'selection' && toState.name === 'payment.details') {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('home');
        }

        if (fromState.name !== 'payment.confirmation' && toState.name === 'payment.details') {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('home');
        }
});
```

Here's the relevant router info for the states:

```
.state('payment', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/payment',
      templateUrl: 'app/views/payment.html'
})

.state('payment.details', {
    url: '/details',

    views: {
     'main': {
       templateUrl: 'app/views/cc-payment.html',
       controller: 'PaymentFormCtrl'
     }
   }
 })

.state('payment.confirm', {
      url: '/confirm',

      views: {
       'main': {
         templateUrl: 'app/views/cc-confirm.html',
         controller: 'PaymentFormCtrl'
       }
     }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        if ((fromState.name == 'selection' || fromState.name == 'payment.confirmation ) && toState.name === 'payment.details') {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('payment.details');
        }else{
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('home');
        }
});
```

try this.